# Better to process JSON in Java or Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, json

Simple enough really. I have a horrible amount of JSON to process, 100GB in total. This 100GB is split into files which are typically 1mb each.

So this left me wondering, typically speaking would it be quicker to parse a JSON file in Javascript or would I have similar results processing the file using one of Java's JSON jars?

Now obviously I'd have to multi thread all of this and so on.

Comment: Node.js can do a pretty good job of forking jobs and running multi-threaded

Comment: @user: Yep, that's why I removed my comment :)

Comment: What are you doing with the data after it's parsed? That's another thing to consider.

Answer (score 6):

Use whatever technology you're most adept at, the odds of a massive performance difference are low. V8 (Google's JavaScript engine — best known in the Chrome browser, and in NodeJS in non-browser environments, but which can also be run standalone) is freaky fast, as is Sun/Oracle's JVM with its excellent hotspot optimization technology. You could even use JavaScript on the JVM if you like ([Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)).

> Now obviously I'd have to multi thread all of this and so on.

It's not obvious at all. If the process is I/O bound (and if you're reading a thousand 100MB files, it sounds like it probably will be, depending on what you're doing with them), adding multiple threads won't help you.

Comment: Important point here, 100GB won't fit into main memory, so I/O performance might be the bottleneck and should be optimized rather than the processing code.

Comment: 1st of all you've already said that those 100GB are spread across multiple files (otherwise concurrency wouldnt be trivial at all) so they dont need to fit in memory.
having said that i'd take a look at java's support for memory mapped files (under the nio package) - i dont think node.js has anything equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

i think it'd be easier, faster, and more easily scalable (ThreadPoolExecutor) to process in java.
how were you planning to do it with javascript? stand alone v8 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know it, I'd use Node.js. Better to handle JSON objects in an environment built on Javascript

Comment: How is it better? JSON is meant to be a portable format. In my experience, Java does a pretty good job of dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Both languages are run in a virtual execution environement so the  execution speed will the more dependent on the VM you use and recent VMs have become really fast especially on recent hardware.

To my knowledge, javascript doesn't have 'native' support for threading. Multithreading was implemented in a "time shared" execution to prevent lockups. This seems however to no longer be the case with ["webworkers"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html) Also you could just split your files across different processes that will independently process the files this will however generate a lot of concurrent disk access which will most probably be your bottleneck when processing your files.

So I'd suggest you go with the language that you are the most comfortable with.

Btw. mind telling us what kind of processing you will be doing on the json files ?

If I were to implement this: to limit concurrent IO, I'd have a 1st thread that will prefetch one file at a time and read it into memory and queue a worker to process that file (if the processing is heavy a threadpool will certainly improve processing speed).